# Flutter email input formatter does not work

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter TextFormField for email with input formatter as below.

```dart
var emailAddressFormatter = FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
    r"[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

The problem is, when trying to input any character in the field it does not allow. The regex looks fine to me. When the formatter is removed the field accepts any character with any format. What am I going wrong?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+ Can you try this RegEx ?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't use those broken regex for email.  Use package:email_validator, which parses it properly.  An actual regex to parse an email address is no less than the regex on this page: https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Yes, that's 6425 characters!  Anything shorter than that is BROKEN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `FilteringTextInputFormatter` that you're using rejects anything that does not match your regex. When you enter just a single character, it does not match your regex, so the character is rejected.

I know little about regex so I'm not sure if it's possible, but you would need a regex that would be able to match every string as you type e.g. `a`, `am`, `amani@`, `amani@gmail.com`.

---

I would personally not try to do filtering such as this. Instead, I would just allow all valid characters that are valid in email addresses to be present in the email and not enforce the specific format with the `@` and `.`. Then I would use a validator to check that the email is valid upon form submission.

---

If you don't like the alternate solution I proposed above and you can't use regex, you can make your own input formatter quite easily with [`TextInputFormatter.withFunction`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter/withFunction.html).